# Why javascript accept types in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to know why this javascript file works in visual studio code.

[image]

Comment: @PM77-1 I think ECMA 6 does not have strong types.

Comment: @canon It's not because my file is a '.js' and not a '.ts'.

Comment: [`JScript.NET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974588.aspx) supports optional type annotations.

Comment: @PM77-1 Nice, can be that. I'll try to confirm. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Code uses the TypeScript brain to understand JavaScript code: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages#_javascript. It exposes a configuration setting which controls if TypeScript specifics should be ignore, a warning, or an error. In you user settings do this:

```
{
    "javascript.validate.lint.typeScriptSpecifics": "error"
}
```

Comment: That's a good find. To test, I set that to "ignore", and the "transcompile" errors went away. Setting **javascript.validate.lint.unusedVariables** and **javascript.validate.lint.unusedFunctions** removed the other warnings. But, if we are ignoring TypeScript specifics, why is there an error when calling "name" with the wrong parameter type?

Comment: Nice, but I tried all options "ignore", "warning" and "error" and none seems to understand the error.

Answer (score 1):

That's TypeScript. That parameters are decorated with data types. But, your function accepts two parameters, and you're only passing one. The second parameter needs to be optional, like this:

```
function(a: string, b?:any) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but typescript uses a .ts file and not a .js

Comment: I just noticed that in the comments above, too. So, I can see why it's a mystery. I tried that in Code, and rather than a red error, I get a green warning that says: "Do not use a TypeScript specific language construct in JavaScript". So, Code seems to know it's JavaScript.